# Nested foreach in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I have view like this

```
<?php foreach ($category as $c) { ?>
<li><?php echo $c['name_category'];?></li>

<?php foreach ($sub_category as $sc) {
if($sc['id_category']==$c['id_category']) { ?>
  <ul>
    <li><?php echo $sc['subname_category'];?></li>
  </ul> 
<?php } } }?>
```

results from the view is

[image]

but I want a look like this

[image]

Comment: To fix the design use css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer `li` is not wrapping the child elements. First, fix your PHP code as follows and add style `display: inline-block` to all outer elements.

```
<?php foreach ($category as $c) { ?>
<li style="display: inline-block"><?php echo $c['name_category'];?>

<?php foreach ($sub_category as $sc) {
if($sc['id_category']==$c['id_category']) { ?>
  <ul>
    <li><?php echo $sc['subname_category'];?></li>
  </ul> 
<?php } } ?> </li> <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each category in a  and css float:left them.

```
<?php foreach ($category as $c) { ?>

<div>

<li><?php echo $c['name_category'];?></li>

<?php foreach ($sub_category as $sc) {
if($sc['id_category']==$c['id_category']) { ?>
  <ul>
    <li><?php echo $sc['subname_category'];?></li>
  </ul> 
<?php } 

 </div>

 } 
 }?>
```